# Creating a publisher that collects values after a trigger

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine, publisher

Is there a way to turn on the collect() after it sees a certain value and then turn it off after it sees another?

I tried using map and filter upstream and that's totally wrong.

Here's my playground

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Combine

var subj = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

for iter in 0...10 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(iter)) {
        print("send \(iter)")
        subj.send(iter)
    }
}

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Q")

let cancellable = subj.collect(.byTime(queue, .seconds(2))).sink(receiveCompletion: {
    print("finish")
    print($0)
}, receiveValue: {
    print($0)
})

/* my print
send 0
send 1
send 2
[0, 1]
send 3
send 4
[2, 3]
send 5 
send 6
[4, 5] // is there a way to only have it dispatch all the values after this point? After it sees a value of 5?
send 7
send 8
[6, 7]
send 9
send 10
[8, 9, 10]

*/
```

Comment: So you want it to print all of `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` at the very end, and not `[6, 7]`?

Comment: One obvious way to do this is to map into a tuple with a Boolean that says whether we've seen a trigger and filter on the boolean (and map back).

Comment: @Sweeper I want it to print only [6, 7] and [8, 9 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this would be to employ the `drop(untilOutputFrom:)` and `prefix(untilOutputFrom:)` operators.

Consider the playground below.

In the code I create a signal `startEmitting` that doesn't emit anything until it sees the value `5`.  Then it emits a "true" value and stops.

Similarly the signal `stopEmitting` waits until it sees a `9` and when it does it emits a single value and stops.

The combined signal drops every value until `startEmitting` fires, and using `prefix` only emits values until `stopEmitting` fires.  The net effect is that the combined signal only starts when a `5` is emitted and stops when `9` is emitted.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Combine

var subj = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

for iter in 0...10 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(iter)) {
        print("send \(iter)")
        subj.send(iter)
        
        if iter == 10 {
            subj.send(completion: .finished)
        }
    }
}

let startEmitting = subj
    .print("startEmtting")
    .contains(5)

let stopEmitting = subj
    .print("stopEmitting")
    .contains(9)

let cancellable = subj
    .drop(untilOutputFrom: startEmitting)
    .prefix(untilOutputFrom: stopEmitting)
    .collect()
    .sink {
    print("finish")
    print($0)
} receiveValue: {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. You understood the essence of the question.

Comment: I have another question that you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73655294/custom-publisher-acting-up-when-upstream-is-subscribed-by-multiple-subscribers