# Custom publisher acting up when upstream is subscribed by multiple subscribers

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

My custom publisher acts strangely if I have another subscriber subscribing to the upstream publisher.

So in my example, my upstream publisher gates the values dispatched

```
let onlyGreaterThan4 = pub.drop(while: { value in
    return value < 4
})
```

I have two subscribers, one with a normal sink and one in a custom publisher.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Combine

var iter = 0
var pub: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().map { _ -> Int in
    iter += 1
    print("sending \(iter)")
    return iter
}.eraseToAnyPublisher()

/// Collects values and starts a timer after the `first` value from upstream is received. This differs from the collect(.byTime) publisher since that publisher collects on an interval
public struct CollectOnReceive<T: Publisher>: Publisher where T.Failure == Never {
    public typealias Output = [T.Output]
    public typealias Failure = T.Failure

    /// Subscription for ReactiveSwiftPublisher
    class Subscription<SubscriberType: Subscriber>: Combine.Subscription where SubscriberType.Input == Output, SubscriberType.Failure == Failure {
        private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set()

        private let subscriber: SubscriberType
        private let upstream: T
        private let queue: DispatchQueue
        private var collection: Output = []

        init(upstream: T, subscriber: SubscriberType, queue: DispatchQueue) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.queue = queue
        }

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            let subscriber = self.subscriber

            Swift.print("-- observing --")

            // collect all the values
            self.upstream.subscribe(on: self.queue)
                .sink { [weak self] value in
                    Swift.print("-- appending: \(value)")
                    self?.collection.append(value)
                }.store(in: &self.cancellables)

            // on the first item
            self.upstream.first()
                .flatMap({ _ -> AnyPublisher<Date, Never> in
                    // dvttodo using dispatch interval timer might be necessary
                    Swift.print("start: \(Date())")
                    return Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }).subscribe(on: self.queue)
                .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                    guard let collection = self?.collection else {
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                        return
                    }

                    Swift.print("--finish sub: \(collection) : \(Date())")
                    subscriber.receive(collection)
                    subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                }).store(in: &self.cancellables)
        }

        func cancel() {
            self.cancellables.removeAll()
        }
    }

    private let upstream: T
    private let queue: DispatchQueue

    public init(upstream: T, queue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.upstream = upstream
        self.queue = queue
    }

    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, T.Failure == S.Failure, [T.Output] == S.Input {
        subscriber.receive(
            subscription: Subscription(
                upstream: self.upstream,
                subscriber: subscriber,
                queue: self.queue
            )
        )
    }
}

extension Publisher where Failure == Never {
    func collectOnReceive(queue: DispatchQueue = .init(label: "CollectOnReceive")) -> CollectOnReceive<Self> {
        return CollectOnReceive(upstream: self, queue: queue)
    }
}

let onlyGreaterThan4 = pub.drop(while: { value in
    return value < 4
})

let q = DispatchQueue(label: "ASDF")

let cancel = onlyGreaterThan4.collectOnReceive(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "collect on receive")).sink {
    print("completion: \($0)")
} receiveValue: {
    print("values: \($0)")
}

let c2 = onlyGreaterThan4.sink {
    print("c2 sink: \($0)")
}

// if you comment out c2, it acts mostly reasonable, the publisher completes properly and sends out the following array [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], don't know what happened to the 5 but that's mostly correct.

// if you leave second subscription with c2 in tact, then it returns the following: [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]. Where did all the odd numbers go? No idea.
```

I figure I must be dealing with the dispatch queues wrong or something silly.

The reason I created a custom publisher was that I wanted value collection for an interval only after the first value greater than or equal to 4 was discovered. Using collect(.byTime) would not be suitable since it executes on the interval, regardless of when upstream values come into it.

So the pseudo code of the goal

```
when x >= 4 was detected then {
    collect(values, for: timeInterval) { valuesGreaterThanEqualTo4 in 
        if valuesGreaterThanEqualTo4.count > threshold {
            return sustained 
        }

        return notSustained
    }
}
```

Update:
I noticed in my print that my sink subscription all my even values where going there while my odd values were going to my custom publisher. So weird.

```
-- observing --
sending 1
sending 2
sending 3
sending 4
c2 sink: 4
sending 5
-- appending: 5
sending 6
start: 2022-09-08 22:45:54 +0000
sending 7
-- appending: 7
sending 8
c2 sink: 8. // missing the append for all the even values!!!
sending 9
-- appending: 9
sending 10
c2 sink: 10
sending 11
-- appending: 11
sending 12
c2 sink: 12
sending 13
-- appending: 13
sending 14
c2 sink: 14
sending 15
-- appending: 15
sending 16
c2 sink: 16
--finish sub: [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15] : 2022-09-08 22:45:59 +0000
values: [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Comment: Don’t you need .shared() on the upstream with multiple subscribers?

Comment: I'm not even aware that such a thing existed. Are you saying I should use this scheduler in my custom publisher?

Comment: @cora Yeah you're right, adding the share() did it.

Comment: How do you know when you need to use shared() and when you don't? I have had multiple objects subscribe from a subject without a problem. I was subscribing with those experiences in mind.

Comment: I use it with multiple subscribers, like Apple recommends. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/share()

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your problem statement, but let me try.  See the playground below.

My `integers` is the same thing as your `pub` but without the global variable.  Hiding it in the `scan` operator will keep anyone else from messing with it :-)

Next, you want all the integers greater than 4. So we create a signal for that with `moreThan4`.  I'm going to use that as the base for more than one other signal that should all share the same value so I added the `.share()` operator.

Now you want the system to signal you when it first encounters a value greater than 4.  Let's capture that explicitly with a signal.  `startCollecting` will send a message when the first value greater than 4 is encountered.

When we get that message we want to transform it into a new signal.  Transformation is the job of a `map` operation.  In this case we want to transform the message into a new **signal** (instead of into a new value). The operator for turning values into new signals is `flatMap`.

The signal we want to transform the "start collecting" event into is one which reads from `moreThan4` over time interval.  And we only want to measure the first time interval.  So we express that in code... collect from `moreThan4` for 5 seconds and return the first such collection.

Is that what you were trying to accomplish?

```
import Foundation
import Combine

let integers = Timer.publish(every: 1.0,
                             on: RunLoop.main,
                             in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .scan(0) { count, _ in
        return count + 1
    }

let moreThan4 = integers
    .filter { $0 > 4 }
    .share()

let startCollecting = moreThan4.first()

let subscription = startCollecting
    .flatMap { _ in
        moreThan4
            .collect(.byTime(RunLoop.main, .seconds(5)))
            .first()
    }
    .sink { print($0) }
```